# Problem with nested components in Livewire 3

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewire-3

First of all, thank you for your time. I am using a Livewire component called 'MonumentCrud,' which is a table with information about monuments and a "Remove" action button for each entry. Additionally, the component has a form for adding new monuments. The file defining this component is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Monumento;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;

class MonumentoCrud extends Component
{
    public Collection $monumentos;

    public String $newNombre;
    public String $newAforo;
    public String $newProvincia;

    public function mount(Collection $monumentos=new Collection(), $newNombre = '',$newAforo = '', $newProvincia = 1){
        $this->monumentos = $monumentos;
        $this->newNombre = $newNombre;
        $this->newAforo = $newAforo;
        $this->newProvincia = $newProvincia;

    }

    public function guardar(){
        Monumento::create([
            'nombre' => $this->newNombre,
            'aforo' => $this->newAforo,
            'provincia' => $this->newProvincia,
        ]);
        $this->newNombre = '';
        $this->newAforo = '';
        
        $this->monumentos = Monumento::all();
    }
    #[On('refreshData')]
    public function update(){
        $this->mount(Monumento::all());
        //$this->monumentos = Monumento::all();
        //$this->render();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.monumento-crud');
    }
}
```

On the other hand, for the action buttons, I have created another Livewire component called ActionLinks with the delete link. The file defining this component is:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\Monumento;
use Livewire\Component;

class ActionLinks extends Component
{
    public Monumento $monumento;

    public function mount($monumento = new Monumento())
    {
        $this->monumento = $monumento;
    }
    public function borrar(){
        $this->monumento->delete();
        $this->dispatch('refreshData');
        
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.action-links');
    }
}
```

The file defining the template for MonumentCrud is:

```
<div>
    <form wire:submit='guardar'>
        <input type="text" wire:model="newNombre" >
        <input type="aforo" wire:model="newAforo" >
        <button type="submit">Guardar</button>
    </form>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Aforo</th>
            <th>Contacto</th>
            <th>Acción</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($monumentos as $monumento)
            <tr :key="$monumento->id">
                <td>{{$monumento->nombre}}</td>
                <td>{{$monumento->aforo}}</td>
                @empty($monumento->telefono->telefono)
                <td>Contacto no disponible</td>
                @else
                <td>{{$monumento->telefono->telefono}}</td>
                @endempty
                <td><livewire:action-links :monumento="$monumento" :key="$monumento->id" /></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The file defining the template action-links.blade.php is:

```
<div>
    <a wire:click='borrar'>Remove</a>
</div>
```

As you can see, I have used the key attribute.

The problem arises when clicking a remove button other than the last one. The action button for the last record disappears, and the rest stop working.

Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. According to [documentation](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/components#adding-wirekey-to-foreach-loops) "When looping through data in a Livewire template using @foreach, you must add a unique wire:key attribute to the root element rendered by the loop."

It means I have to add both, the loop's root key with wire:key and the component :key.

So, in the file defining the template for MonumentCrud, I changed:

```
@foreach($monumentos as $monumento)
            <tr :key="$monumento->id">
```

for

```
@foreach($monumentos as $monumento)
            <tr wire:key="identif-{{$monumento->id}}">
```